# VHDL: setting a constant conditionally based on another constant's value

Tags: vhdl

I need to set a constant's value using an "if-else" or "case", and select a different constant value based on another constant's value.  Is this possible in VHDL?  It would be a one time change of constant values at the beginning of simulation...  Example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity bridge is
    generic (
        burst_mode    :std_logic  := '0'
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of bridge is

    constant  fifo_aw_wdata  :natural := 2 when (burst_mode = '0') else 5; 

begin

--   fifo: entity work myfifo
--      generic map(
--          aw => fifo_aw_wdata
--      )
--      port map(
--          ...
--      );

end architecture;
```

The above VHDL code gives the error message:

```
Error ';' is expected instead of 'when'
```

In Verilog, Its very easy to do this type of thing...so I assume VHDL has a away to do this as well?  Verilog example:

```
    module #(parameter burst_mode = 1'b0) bridge;

    localparam fifo_aw_wdata = (!burst_mode) ? 2 : 5;

    // fifo myfifo #(.aw(fifo_aw_wdata)) ( ...);

    endmodule;
```

Comment: Vhdl 2019 will (finally) allow this code.

Answer (score 7):

This solution is a little bit strange, but it works:

```
architecture rtl of bridge is

    function setup1(s:std_logic; i0:integer; i1:integer) 
        return integer is
    begin
        if s = '1' then
            return i1;
        else
            return i0;
        end if;
    end function;

    constant  fifo_aw_wdata  :natural := setup1(burst_mode, 2, 5);

begin

--   fifo: entity work myfifo
--      generic map(
--          aw => fifo_aw_wdata
--      )
--      port map(
--          ...
--      );

end architecture;
```

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it, and VHDL overloading allows you to declare multiple functions with the same name but different argument and result types, whereby the VHDL compiler will apply the right function like magic ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Correct answers have been posted, but there are also one-line alternatives.

The simplest solution is to change the datatype of burst_mode to integer with range 0 to 1, and then use some math:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity bridge is
    generic (
        burst_mode    :integer range 0 to 1 := 0
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of bridge is
    constant  fifo_aw_wdata  :natural := 2 + burst_mode * 3; 
begin
```

If the datatype of burst_mode cannot be changed, then you can also do it with a type conversion:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity bridge is
    generic (
        burst_mode    :std_logic  := '0'
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of bridge is
    constant  fifo_aw_wdata  :natural := 2 + to_integer(unsigned('0' & burst_mode)) * 3; 
begin
```

Answer (score 2):

Though pico posted an answer already, it is a very relevant question worthy of elaboration.

The declaration of the function may be similar to "conditional expressions" or "ternary if" in other languages like Python with `res_true if cond else res_false` or C with `cond ? res_true : res_false`.

The condition is then a boolean, and the result for `true` comes before the result for `false`.  The declaration could be like:

```
function tif(cond : boolean; ref_true, ref_false : integer) return integer is
begin
  if cond then
    return res_true;
  else
    return res_false;
  end if;
end function;
```

And having multiple functions with different result types, a version for `real` could also be defined like:

```
function tif(cond : boolean; res_true, res_false : real) return real is
begin
  if cond then
    return res_true;
  else
    return res_false;
  end if;
end function;
```